# Save a list into a .txt file and read it back from file to list

Tags: python, list, file, tuples

I'm struggling to save a list into a .txt file and read it back from .txt file to a list in Python.

Here is my List

```
SS1=[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
```

Save each tuple line by line in a readable format to ABC.Txt...not ascii or encrypted.

And need an another routine to read the ABC.Txt back into a list in Python.

here is my code which i can't read the physical file in notepad or something

```
def List2File(MyList,fname,msg):
    start_time = STime()
    with open(fname, 'wb') as fp:
        pickle.dump(MyList, fp)
    end_time = ETime()
    if (msg=='Y'):
        print(fname ,'Saved.../', 
    return()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems have you encountered? We could write the whole program for you, but that is not the purpose of StackOverflow.

Comment: What do you mean by "readable" format (in opposition to ASCII)?

Comment: def List2File(MyList,fname,msg):
    start_time = STime()
    with open(fname, 'wb') as fp:
        pickle.dump(MyList, fp)
    end_time = ETime()
    if (msg=='Y'):
        print(fname ,'Saved.../', file_size(fname),'/',len(fname),ElaspedTime(start_time,end_time),'Seconds')
    return()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SS1=[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]

def write_to_txt(a, file_name, delimiter=','):
    with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        for k in a:
            fmt = '%s' % delimiter
            f.write(fmt.join(map(str, k)) + '\n')

def read_from_txt(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        data = [tuple(map(int, k.split(','))) for k in f.read().splitlines()]
    return data

write_to_txt(SS1, 'ABC.txt')
data  = read_from_txt('ABC.txt')
print(data)
```

Comment: Can u pls make the above routine to work for multiple lists to print in parallel as a table fields and records that how we see in database. Hope not too much work for u...Sorry if any inconvenience is caused.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
SS1=[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
with open('newfile.txt','w') as fileobj:
        fileobj.write('\n'.join('%s' % (x,) for x in SS1))
```

Create a file Object `fileobj` for the 'newfile.txt' with `w` (write mode)

> Make a singleton tuple with our as the only item, i.e. the (thetuple,) and write it in the file.

Comment: Take a look at this solution @johnebenezer

Comment: Thanks buddy for the resposnse

Answer (score 0):

Just use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
SS1 = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
np.savetxt('my_file.txt', SS1)
my_new_SS1 = np.genfromtxt('my_file.txt')
print(my_new_SS1)


Out[1]: [[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
        [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  6.]
        [ 1.  2.  3.  5.  6.]
        [ 1.  2.  4.  5.  6.]
        [ 1.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
        [ 2.  3.  4.  5.  6.]]
```